# A query about class nesting in java

Tags: java, types, inner-classes, variable-declaration

```
public class Outer{
    public class Inner{
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer objOut = new Outer();
        //Outer.Inner object1= objOut.new Inner();  // runes without a problem
        //objOut.Inner object2= objOut.new Inner(); //gives error
    }
}
```

This might sound little amateur but, What are the difference between `Outer.Inner` vs `objOut.Inner`.

Comment: Probably worth a thorough read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html (not saying it's not a good question).

Comment: `objOut.Inner` is invalid, as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a variable name as the *type* of another variable, which is what you're trying to do with `objOut.Inner`. The type of the variable is `Inner` (or optionally `Outer.Inner`).

Because `Inner` is an [*inner class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html), it's associated with an *instance* of its outer class (its *enclosing instance*). When you create an instance of it, you can optionally¹ specify what object instance it's associated with, which is what you're doing with `objOut.new Inner`.

This example may help make it a bit clearer:

```
public class Example {
    private String str;

    public class Inner {
        void show() {
            // Show the string for the Example this Inner is part of
            System.out.println(Example.this.str);
        }
    }

    public Example(String s) {
        this.str = s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e1 = new Example("e1");
        Example e2 = new Example("e2");
        Inner i1 = e1.new Inner();
        i1.show(); // "e1"
        Inner i2 = e2.new Inner();
        i2.show(); // "e2"
    } 
}
```

[Live Copy](http://ideone.com/93S1eB)

Notice how the `i1` `Inner` instance gets `e1` as its enclosing `Example` instance, and so sees `e1`'s `str`, but `i2` gets `e2` as its enclosing instance so it sees `e2`'s `str`.

I suggest [this Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for more information.

---

¹ Sometimes it's not optional, such as in my `Example` class above, since where `new Inner` is used, there's no default instance it could use. It would be optional in an *instance* method of `Example`, but not in that `static` method.

Answer (score 2):

Both don't compile.

To make the former compile, a variable should be declared, and the name to that variable should be given.

```
Outer.Inner obj = objOut.new Inner();
```

The latter wouldn't compile even if you did this step since `objOut.Inner` is neither a type (because the primary expression `objOut` is not a type) nor a valid name (because `.` is not allowed within [an identifier (jls-3.8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)).

A simplified [rule (jls-14.4)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) for your case would be

```
LocalVariableType VariableDeclaratorId [= VariableInitializer];
```

Answer (score 2):

This one :

```
Outer.Inner = objOut.new Inner();
```

will not compile but if you change it to :

```
Outer.Inner object = objOut.new Inner();
```

will mean creating an instance of inner class which has reference to `Outer` class - `objOut` will be instance of `Outer` class.

Also this :

```
objOut.Inner = objOut.new Inner();
```

will not compile since `objOut` which is the instance of `Outer` class does not have poperty `Inner`.

And it is not `Outer` class that knows the instance of `Inner` class - it is `Inner` class instance that knows the `Outer` class instance with which it was created.

**EDIT**

The line :

```
objOut.Inner object2= objOut.new Inner();
```

will not compile since `Inner` type identifer belongs to `Outer` **class** and not instance of this class.